# Рефакторинг кода

Tags: php

Возможно ли сделать рефакторинг этого кода?

```
<?
$ip = false;
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] != '127.0.0.1' && preg_match("#^([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})$#", $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
    $ip2['xff'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    $ipa[]      = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
}
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'] != '127.0.0.1' && preg_match("#^([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})$#", $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
    $ip2['cl'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    $ipa[]     = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
}
if (isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) && preg_match("#^([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})$#", $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {
    $ip2['add'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $ipa[]      = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
$ip     = $ipa[0];
$iplong = ip2long($ip);
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
    $ua = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    $ua = strtok($ua, '/');
    $ua = strtok($ua, '('); // оставляем только то, что до скобки
    $ua = preg_replace('#[^a-z_\./ 0-9\-]#iu', null, $ua); // вырезаем все "левые" символы
    // Опера мини тоже посылает данные о телефоне :)
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_OPERAMINI_PHONE_UA']) && preg_match('#Opera#i', $ua)) {
        $ua_om = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_OPERAMINI_PHONE_UA'];
        $ua_om = strtok($ua_om, '/');
        $ua_om = strtok($ua_om, '(');
        $ua_om = preg_replace('#[^a-z_\. 0-9\-]#iu', null, $ua_om);
        $ua    = 'Opera Mini (' . $ua_om . ')';
    }
} else
    $ua = 'Нет данных';
?>
```

Comment: да это возможно.

Comment: дайте еще советы пожалуйста

Comment: А ещё, невооруженным взглядом видны два, практически идентичных блока по 3 строки. Можно аккуратно сделать две функции.

Comment: Скажите, что вы хотели сделать? Каков результат выполнения данного кода? Возможно вы не правильно реализовали свою задачу.

Comment: Этот код выдран из DCMS 6.6.4)) Глядим движок и файл по пути /sys/inc/ipua.php

Answer (score 5):

Первую часть можно отрефакторить при помощи клавиши `delete` (мой любимый вид рефакторинга):

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$iplong = ip2long($ip);
```

А во второй части, парсинг `User Agent` можно вынести в функцию и заменить не очевидный `strtok()` на регулярное выражение:

```
function parse_ua($ua) {
    if (!empty($_SERVER[$ua]) && preg_match('#^[\w\d\s_/.-]+#S', $_SERVER[$ua], $m)) {

        return $m[0];
    }

    return false;
}

if ($ua = parse_ua('HTTP_USER_AGENT')) {

    if (strpos('Opera', $ua) !== false && ($ua_om = parse_ua('HTTP_X_OPERAMINI_PHONE_UA')) {

        $ua = "Opera Mini ($ua_om)";
    }

} else {
    $ua = 'Нет данных';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Первое, что можно сделать - значения переменных с длинными именами присвоить коротким, к примеру:

```
$forward = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
```

Comment: И что от этого измениться ?

Comment: Будет меньше кода, и его будет легче воспринимать.

Comment: @Error, т.к. переменные с длинными именами используются по несколько раз, то это сократит код и сделает его красивее и понятнее.

Comment: регулярку на IP тоже можно в переменную вынести

Comment: всем спасибо

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
const UriPattern = "#^([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})$#";
$ip = false;
$isServerOk = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] != '127.0.0.1';
$ServerPregmatch = preg_match(UriPattern, $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']);
if ($isServerOk && $ServerPregmatch) {
  $ip2['xff'] = $ipa[] = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
}
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'] != '127.0.0.1' && preg_match(UriPattern, $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
  $ip2['cl'] = $ipa[] = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
}
if (isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) && preg_match(UriPattern, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {
  $ip2['add'] = $ipa[] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
$ip     = $ipa[0];
$iplong = ip2long($ip);
/**
* @param $uri
* @return mixed|string
*/
function formatUriStr($uri)
{
  $uri = strtok($uri, '/');
  $uri = strtok($uri, '('); // оставляем только то, что до скобки
  $uri = preg_replace('#[^a-z_\./ 0-9\-]#iu', null, $uri);
  return $uri; // вырезаем все "левые" символы
}

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
  $ua = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
  $ua = formatUriStr($ua);
  // Опера мини тоже посылает данные о телефоне :)
  if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_OPERAMINI_PHONE_UA']) && preg_match('#Opera#i', $ua)) {
     $ua_om = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_OPERAMINI_PHONE_UA'];
     $ua_om = formatUriStr($ua_om);
     $ua    = 'Opera Mini (' . $ua_om . ')';
  }
} else
  $ua = 'Нет данных';
```